# VS2015 : NUnit : Could not copy 'source dll localtion' to 'destination dll localtion'. Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, nunit-2.5.9

I'm working on web API project. I have written unit tests and i am using Nunit to run these tests. I encountered this strange error.

I opened Nunit.exe and under Project > Add Assembly i specify my dll which has unit tests. I click Run and tests execute fine.

I go back to Visual Studio 2015 and make some edits to my tests and Build. It says,

```
Could not copy 'location/of/dll'. Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
The process cannot access the file 'location/of/dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

When i close NUnit application, build works fine.

But this was not the case a few hours back. Whenever i click Build in VS2015, in Nunit GUI it used to display `Reloading..` and the dll used to reload.

I have to `close Nunit > Build in VS > Open Nunit > Add assembly reference > Run` to run my test cases. Has anyone faced the same isuue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your nunit project to the same location as the dll files are.
I heard that it has to do with the shadow copy.

Here are some places, where a similar question has been asked.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182841/nunit-locking-dll)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935244/nunit-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I ll try putting the projects in the same location. I didn't get suggestion that the question is duplicate while i was asking the question. :D

Comment: u ll know if i have accepted it as answer or not.. :D